# Who was Colonel Palmer of the Mitla Pass?

Tags: british-empire, egypt, monument

From [Marshall, *Sinai Victory*](https://archive.org/details/sinaivictorycomm00mars):

[image]

> What is called "Parker's Memorial" in this book, and is herein
> pictured, is described in a reliable source as a monument to the
> memory of Col. A. C. Palmer, DSO, a valiant British officer who was
> twice governor of Sinai. But the troops who went there insisted on
> calling it "Parker's Memorial" however it was dedicated, and they
> certainly knew where they were going. The late Colonel Palmer should
> not mind that, in rehallowing the spot, they were a mite careless
> about its name.

So, who was Colonel Palmer and what is the memorial about?

(And is the monument still there or what happened to it?)

**Edit**: [Hebrew wikipedia](https://he-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%A8?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp) has some answers (spelling regularised):

> The Parker Monument [was] a monument to the memory of Colonel [Alfred
> Chevalier Parker](https://family-tree.cobboldfht.com/people/view/5778), which was built in the 1920s at the eastern
> entrance of the Mitla Pass in Sinai, Egypt and was destroyed by Egypt
> after Israel's withdrawal from Sinai in 1957. [...] Colonel Parker was the
> British governor of Sinai in the years [1907-1912], and 1918-1923[.] The
> [monument] was erected at the eastern entrance of the [Mitla] pass by
> Parker's successor as governor of Sinai, [Claude Jarvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Scudamore_Jarvis), since Parker
> was the one who initiated the construction of the stone road in the
> sands from [El Shatt] to the western entrance of the [Mitla pass.]

**And**: the name Palmer may be a confusion with [Edward Henry Palmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Henry_Palmer), who was murdered in the area, as noted in comments.

Comment: As a possibility: confusion between [Albert Palmer](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-suez-crisis-1956-albert-palmer-of-birmingham-a-gunner-from-a-parachute-20044903.html?imageid=F03E94A2-3504-4855-B68C-C5A21032E14A&p=62486&pn=1&searchId=7fa914b7f11365e37d8e30bd02600d85&searchtype=0) and linguist [E.H. Palmer](https://www.joh.cam.ac.uk/eh-palmer-colleges-own-lawrence-arabia). The former is indeed related to the Suez crisis, but by then Parker Memorial already existed and was called this way. The latter has extensively traveled through Sinai and Gaza. He was murdered in that area.

Comment: I assume this reviewer is blowing smoke. If the memorial is for a Palmer, then EH makes more sense: https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:73df7355-b69b-4e60-af97-e5b5634fd886/download_file?file_format=application%2Fpdf&safe_filename=Hewitson_2022_monument_to_MenAM.pdf

Comment: BTW, Hebrew Wikipedia has an article on the monument: https://he-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%A8?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: "The murder of the English Orientalist, Professor Henry Palmer, by bedouin, in 1882, was commemorated by a cairn of stones, after which the site of this murder has since been called Cairn Spring - eAyn Abii Rijm." (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/peq.1984.116.1.42

Comment: The Hebrew Wikipedia article identifies the honorand as Alfred Chevallier Parker; Google translate says it is his tombstone.  According to it the monument was built in the 1920's. According to https://family-tree.cobboldfht.com/people/view/5778 , Parker died in 1935 in Glouscestershire.  The website points to https://commons-wikimedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Category:Parker_Memorial,_Sinai_Peninsula?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp which shows several views of the monument, and repeats the 1920's date.

Comment: A. C. Parker was the youngest son of Harry Rainy and Frances Emily Jane (née Kitchener) Parker, and a nephew of Lord Kitchener. He was born on 3 June 1874 at Waihao, Waimate, New Zealand, and died at West Field, Minchinhampton, Gloucestershire, on 27 December 1935. Curiously, sources differ on the dates of his governorship, with the earliest start date given as 1906. But all list 1923 as the end of his second term in that position. The monument inscription (see link in kimchi lover's comment) confirms 1906 start date for the first term as governor.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/viV1v.jpg

Answer (score 1):

All the available evidence suggests that the quote from Marshall, which cites some unspecified "reliable source", is simply wrong.

Except for the last name, **Alfred Chavelier Parker** perfectly fits Marshall's description of who "A. C. Palmer" allegedly was: colonel and two-term governor of Sinai until 1923 per [his obituary](https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/raaf19), and also DSO per [an article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03068372808724991) he wrote about Sinai. The quote added to the question from Hebrew Wikipedia correctly states that the Parker monument in Sinai was dedicated to A. C. Parker in the 1920s and destroyed in the 1950s. [One of the photos of the monument on Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Sinai_%28997009157308705171.jpg), while difficult to read, shows the dates of two terms of governorship which roughly align with those given in Parker's obituary.

To speculate a bit about where Marshall's confusion may have come from, an [E. H. Palmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Henry_Palmer) was ambushed and killed in Sinai in August 1882. According to [an article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/peq.1984.116.1.42) on place names in Sinai, a [cairn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairn) was built at the site of the ambush. The article also discusses the Parker monument and it is clearly not the same location. I have not seen any images of this cairn if they exist, but the Parker monument is at least vaguely cairn-like. However I would not assert with any confidence that Marshall's unnamed source was somehow mixing up A. C. Parker and E. H. Palmer.